# Pass the n output of previous command to next command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

given this example input :

```
➜ ls
conf.txt  config.file  one.file  two.file
```

How could I access a specific element of the command output ?
Say one.file for instance.

Related questions just refer to pipes , $(!!) and the alike. But I couldn't find information for this specific task that would improve speed in certain scenarios where piping is not that useful.

Similarly to what `history` does with numbered outputs and the use of !n for access.

#Edit after excellent solutions given:#

Would like to find a way to use the last command output without:

- using pipe `|`
- storing the `output=` beforehand

Comment: You can use arrays : `output=($(find . -type f | sort)); echo "${output[2]}"`

Comment: another tip : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: Nice one! Didn't know about ${ }! Going to try and see. What's the search term for this kind of commands or where can I find more documentation about the topic?

Comment: `${output[2]}` -> [bash arrays](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/arrays/) ; `find . -type f` -> [bash find](https://math2001.github.io/article/bashs-find-command/) ; `$( ... )` -> [command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks for the links , going to read it thoroughly. Even tho my original question inteded to be simpler than typing it manually on the next terminal command with no need for assigning a var etc , but its a good thing to learn. I guess Im looking for something inexistent

Comment: You can use aliases for that. I'll write an answer with a sample alias in a little while

Comment: @Aserre, `readarray -t output < <(find ...)` is safer than `output=($(find ...))` -- readarray won't split filenames containing spaces into separate array elements.

Answer (score 1):

As per the precisions added in the comments, you can use arrays to store and access the desired element. Fore instance, you can use the following commands :

```
➜ find . -type f | sort
conf.txt  config.file 'file with space.txt' one.file  two.file
➜ readarray -t output < <(find . -type f | sort)
➜ echo "${output[2]}"
file with space.txt
```

In order to make this easier to use, you can paste the following alias in your `.bashrc` file :

```
getElement() {
    index="$1"
    re='^[0-9]+$'
    if [[ ! "$index" =~ $re ]]
    then
        echo "getElement : argument must be a number - got $index"
        return 1
    else
        readarray -t output <&0  # <&0 is used to read from the piped command
        echo "${output[$index]}"
    fi
}
```

You then call it like that : `find . -type f | sort | getElement 2`

---

If you want to read the output from the last executed command, you can add the following alias to `~/.bashrc`

```
getElementLastCommand() {
    index="$1"
    re='^[0-9]+$'
    if [[ ! "$index" =~ $re ]]
    then
        echo "getElementLastCommand : argument must be a number - got $index"
    else
        # this retrieves and execute the last command from the history
        readarray -t output < <($(history -w /dev/stdout | tail -n 2  | head -1))
        echo "${output[$index]}"
    fi
}
```

**WARNING** : this executes the last command from your history again. This works for programs that produces the same output everytime, like `ls` (in the same folder), but something like `echo $RANDOM` will not yield the same results. I don't think what you are looking for is 100% possible without storing the output of your command somewhere (temporary variable, file, etc...)

---

From the comments, here are some links to read more about the tools used in the script :

- [Don't parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)
- [Bash arrays](https://www.shell-tips.com/bash/arrays/#gsc.tab=0)
- [Bash find](https://math2001.github.io/article/bashs-find-command/)
- [Command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash)

Comment: This is excellent! Perfect for the task. I'm going to edit a bit the description with more eloquent intended use, I'm almost giving it up on finding a way without pipes, just after the output is already been displayed and is not stored in a var beforehand

Comment: @CarloCattano expanded my answer to handle the case you described